# Algorithm for Dynamic Programming of Kleinberg Book

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I need help for this about answer and program of it with C.

From Kleinberg & Tardos's (2006) *Algorithm Design*, pp. 334–335:

> **29.** Let $G = (V , E)$ be a graph with $n$ nodes in which each pair of nodes is joined by an edge. There is a positive weight $w_{ij}$ on each edge $(i, j)$; and we will assume these weights satisfy the *triangle inequality* $w_{ik} ≤ w_{ij} + w_{jk}$. For a subset $V' ⊆ V$, we will use $G[V' ]$ to denote the subgraph (with edge weights) induced on the nodes in $V'$.
>
> We are given a set $X ⊆ V$ of $k$ *terminals* that must be connected by edges. We say that a *Steiner tree* on $X$ is a set $Z$ so that $X ⊆ Z ⊆ V$, together with a spanning subtree $T$ of $G[Z]$. The weight of the Steiner tree is the weight of the tree $T$.
>
> Show that there is function $f(·)$ and a polynomial function $p(·)$ so that the problem of finding a minimum-weight Steiner tree on $X$ can be solved in time $O(f(k)·p(n))$.

Comment: I edited to clean up some of the math formatting, but some things were missing in the original.  E.g., $V \subseteq V$.  Should the first $V$ be a $V'$ or something similar?

Comment: mmm, i copy it from the pdf of the keleinberg book. maybe they wrote wrong... it should be V'. i edit it now

Comment: This exercise is directly from the textbook (I added the reference).  It's not clear what your question is.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : i want to program it with C++, but i dont know how ... :-s

Comment: The original question said C, not C++, so I've edited it to reflect that.  Even so, if the question is fundamentally about programming, it's probably suited better for StackOverflow than MSE.

Comment: As @JoshuaTaylor wrote, the part of your question about "program of it with C" is off topic at this site. The part where one is asked to show the existence of the functions $f$ and $p$, however, can be on topic.

Comment: ok. can someone tell how to solve it?not code of it. just how to solve